# Removing "object having an array field" from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my code:

```
var subMed = [ {med:'bm', sub:[ 'a' , 'b' ]} , {med:'bm', sub:[ 'c' , 'd' , 'e' ]} ];
    var sal = [ {num:"1",amount:"500"} ];
    var t = {Class:"1", subMeds:subMed, numOfSub:2, sals:sal };
    var infoAcademic = [];
    infoAcademic.push(t);

    subMed = [ {med:'em', sub:[ 'p']} , {med:'bm', sub:[ 'r' , 's' ]} ];
    sal =  [ {num:"2",amount:"1500"},{num:"1",amount:"700"} ];
    t = {Class:"1", subMeds:subMed, numOfSub:1, sals:sal };
    infoAcademic.push(t);

    var tempObj = infoAcademic[1];   // an object
    var mediumSubjects = tempObj["subMeds"];  // an array

    console.log(mediumSubjects);

    for(i=0;i<mediumSubjects.length;i++){
        var temp = {};  // object
        temp = mediumSubjects[i];
        if(temp["med"] == 'bm'){

            tempObj["numOfSub"] = tempObj["numOfSub"] - temp["sub"].length;
            var salArr = tempObj["sals"];  // array
            var j = salArr.length;
            if(salArr.length > 0){
                while(j--){  
                    var salObj = salArr[j];  // object
                    var howManySub = salObj["num"];
                    if(howManySub > tempObj["numOfSub"]){
                        salArr.splice(j,1);
                    }
                }
            }


            console.log("removing from the medSubjects list: ");
            console.log(temp);
            var removed = mediumSubjects.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log("removed element: ");
    console.log(removed);
    console.log(mediumSubjects);
```

When I write this code this an online js editor https://js.do/ , the code gives result as per expected. But when I incorporate this code in a `onclick` function of my JSP page, no element gets removed from the `mediumSubjects` array. The removed element shows empty.

However, when I comment out this portion:

```
tempObj["numOfSubj"] = tempObj["numOfSub"] - temp["sub"].length;
var salArr = tempObj["sals"];  // array
var j = salArr.length;
if(salArr.length > 0){
     while(j--){  
          var salObj = salArr[j];  // object
          var howManySub = salObj["num"];
          if(howManySub > tempObj["numOfSub"]){
                salArr.splice(j,1);
          }
     }
}
```

the code surprisingly behaves as expected- it removes the element from the `mediumSubjects` array.

Is there any synchronization issue or something else? Why this sort of unusual behavior?

N.B. I need to remove elements from the array `mediumSubjects`, so `delete` won't work here.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Do you have larger array than shown in the example?

Comment: The code you have posted works. After running it, `medSub` will have only one object element. Also the console command outputs `removed element: [object Object]` (not empty as it is in your question)

Comment: Yes @PankajShukla

Comment: `// prints empty`. Not really. The code seems to be working. Can you check again and post the code that is not working?

Comment: I discovered something interesting and updated the question. Sorry for the inconvenience. But the problem is now more mysterious. @PankajShukla

Answer (score 1):

Try this variant:

```
var newMedSub = medSub.filter(function(elem) {
    return elem.med !== 'em';
});
```

It will help you to get a new array without unnessessary object.

Answer (score 0):

All you actually need is to iterate over the outer array and in the body of this loop you need to iterate over the object keys.

for Example:

```
// removing med key from the array.
medSub.forEach(obj => {
   for (let key in obj) {
      if (key === 'med' && obj[key] === 'em') {
         delete obj[key];
      }
   }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I need to remove the element from the array. "delete" puts an undefined in the place of the element.